# ORA-06550: PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'APEX' reference is out of scope ORA-06550:

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex-5

My program was running all good before i added this statement to the `Execute PL SQL Code` type of the dynamic action provoked by Button Click event.

```
   apex.message.showPageSuccess( 'Action Processed' );
```

The error is

```
  ORA-06550: PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'APEX' 
  reference is out of scope ORA-06550: line 10
```

What I understood is that it is not in the scope of the region. So whats the solution for displaying success notification on a region level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `Execute PL SQL Code` is for executing PL/SQL code - it is an Oracle procedural language, which executes by database engine on the server side. `apex.message.showPageSuccess` - is a part of APEX JavaScript API, i. e. this function is executed by browser on the client side. So you need to change type of your action to `Execute JavaScript Code`.